# Org mode subtitle not being exported to pdf

Tags: org-mode, latex

```
#+TITLE: My title
#+SUBTITLE: My subtitle

* Blah blah blah
```

My subtitle isn't being exported, anyone know why?

LaTeX export: https://pastebin.com/Wg2gVS12

Comment: Can you post the results of the latex buffer export?

Comment: @dangom Added to post

Comment: I meant the LaTeX export, not the PDF LaTeX output. Try `C-c C-e l L` export to LaTeX buffer

Comment: @dangom Sorry, changed

Comment: Interesting. I noticed that you are using an outdated version of Org. Perhaps #+SUBTITLE wasn't supported back then. Can you check the value of `org-latex-subtitle-format`? (`C-h v` `org-latex-subtitle-format` `RET`)

Comment: @dangom That variable isn't defined aha. I guess you are right then. I'm using the version of org that came with emacs. What's the best way to get the new version?

Comment: See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA and https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package

Answer (score 3):

<sup>[Collecting the comment interactions into an answer; thanks to @dangorn for discovering this solution]</sup>

You are using an outdated version of Org that did not yet support `#+SUBTITLE` (if you check the value of `org-latex-subtitle-format` with `C-h v org-latex-subtitle-format RET` it will be undefined). To fix, update your Org Mode (see [MELPA](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA) and [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)).